# Get ISO 3166-2 Regions based on coordinates

Tags: coordinates

I am looking for a way to get the ISO 3166-2 subdivisions based on latitude and longitude. For example JFK airport has the coordinates 40.6413° N, 73.7781° W. and the ISO 3166-2 code is US-NY. Is there a database or a service to retrieve this data?

Comment: Have you checked with the local/state/federal geographic/kartographic offices?

Comment: How about Geonames - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/list-of-language-codes-by-country

Comment: Thanks Ian, by using the endpoint http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision (https://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrysubdiv) I get the ISO 3166-2 codes!

Answer (score 1):

Ian Turton had a good suggestion by checking Geonames.
By using the endpoint api.geonames.org/countrySubdivision (geonames.org/export/web-services.html#countrysubdiv) I get the ISO 3166-2 codes